# Angular 4 Multiple Providers

Tags: angular, service-provider

In my Module I want to insert multiple providers.  But I lose the window provider when adding the APP_INITIALIZER service =

```
providers: [
        AlertService,       
        ConfigurationService,
        LocalStoreManager,                 
        EndpointFactory,        
        BaseComponent,            
        BaseService,
        { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: app_Init, deps:[BaseService], useClass:BaseService, multi:true },
        { provide: 'Window', useValue: window, useClass:window, multi:true }       
    ],
```

Is there a way to do this?

...So that my component can load its window location =

```
@Component({
    selector: 'management-root',
    templateUrl: window["baseUrl"] + '/src/app/components/site/management.html'    
})
```

Comment: What do you mean, you lose the window provider?

Comment: When the page goes to load it first resolves the APP_INITILIZER and that serve returns data.  

Then when it goes to get the templateUrl via window["baseurl"] nothing happens.  I get no errors, but nothing loads. 

Removing the APP_INITIALIZER line from the providers allows the app to load properly.

Comment: I just removed this line from the APP_INITIALIZER provider = multi:true

This brought up the following error = "Mixing multi and non multi provider is not possible for token"

I now think this is related to mixing the multi-provider of APP_INITIALIZER and the single of Window...  

But that does not help me.  I need both to be provided here in the module so they are able to be used in the @Component section before the Constructor ...